# ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams' from 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall matplotlib in my tf-gpu enviornment I made but I keep getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams' from 'matplotlib'
```

This is the entire output I am getting on jupyter notebook:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8d7d44d0fddd> in <module>
     17 # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     18 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
---> 19 from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix
     20 
     21 # Removes annoying warning messages in tensorflow and python

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\plotting\__init__.py in <module>
      5 # License: BSD 3 clause
      6 
----> 7 from .decision_regions import plot_decision_regions
      8 from .learning_curves import plot_learning_curves
      9 from .plot_confusion_matrix import plot_confusion_matrix

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\plotting\decision_regions.py in <module>
      8 
      9 from itertools import cycle
---> 10 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     11 import numpy as np
     12 from mlxtend.utils import check_Xy, format_kwarg_dictionaries

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>
     30 from cycler import cycler
     31 import matplotlib
---> 32 import matplotlib.colorbar
     33 import matplotlib.image
     34 from matplotlib import rcsetup, style

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>
     25 
     26 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 27 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     28 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     29 import matplotlib.collections as collections

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in <module>
     10 
     11 import matplotlib
---> 12 from . import cbook, docstring, rcParams
     13 from .path import Path
     14 from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, Transform, TransformedBbox,

ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams' from 'matplotlib' (unknown location)
```

I was not able to find a solution online, so I wanted to start a thread on this again.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to uninstall matplotlib using conda/pip but it still shows up in conda list output:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu
absl-py                   0.8.1                    py37_0
asn1crypto                1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.0                    py37_0
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2019.11.27                    0
censusdata                1.5                      pypi_0    pypi
censusgeocode             0.4.3.post1              pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0
cffi                      1.12.3                   pypi_0    pypi
chardet                   3.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     7.0                      py37_0
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0
cligj                     0.5.0                    py37_0
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0
cryptography              2.7                      pypi_0    pypi
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.0_0
curl                      7.67.0               h2a8f88b_0
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
et-xmlfile                1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
expat                     2.2.5                he025d50_0
fiona                     1.8.4            py37h22081e2_0
freexl                    1.0.5                hfa6e2cd_0
gast                      0.3.2                      py_0
gdal                      2.3.3            py37hdf43c64_0
geopandas                 0.6.1                      py_0
geos                      3.7.1                h33f27b4_0
grpcio                    1.16.1           py37h351948d_1
h5py                      2.9.0            py37h5e291fa_0
haversine                 2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
hdf4                      4.2.13               h712560f_2
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      pypi_0    pypi
importlib_metadata        1.3.0                    py37_0
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipfn                      1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 5.1.3            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.11.1           py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
jdcal                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.15.2                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0
joblib                    0.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0
kealib                    1.4.7                h07cbb95_6
keras                     2.2.4                         0
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-base                2.2.4                    py37_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
krb5                      1.16.4               hc04afaa_0
libboost                  1.67.0               hd9e427e_4
libcurl                   7.67.0               h2a8f88b_0
libgdal                   2.3.3                h10f50ba_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libkml                    1.3.0                he5f2a48_4
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h411e497_2
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libpq                     11.2                 h3235a2c_0
libprotobuf               3.11.2               h7bd577a_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h33f27b4_0
libspatialite             4.3.0a              hc36aec2_19
libssh2                   1.8.2                h7a1dbc1_0
libtiff                   4.1.0                h56a325e_0
libxml2                   2.9.9                h464c3ec_0
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
matplotlib                3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4            py37he774522_0
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37h675688f_0
mlxtend                   0.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
more-itertools            8.0.2                      py_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
munch                     2.5.0                      py_0
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
networkx                  2.4                      pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.0.2                    py37_0
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h93ca92e_0
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37hc3f5095_1
openpyxl                  3.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1d               he774522_3
pandas                    0.25.3           py37ha925a31_0
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
pcre                      8.43                 ha925a31_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0
plotly                    4.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
proj4                     5.2.0                ha925a31_1
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.2                      py_0
protobuf                  3.11.2           py37h33f27b4_0
pycparser                 2.19                     pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.5.2                      py_0
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyproj                    1.9.6            py37h6782396_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py37_1
pyrsistent                0.15.6           py37he774522_0
python                    3.7.6                h60c2a47_2
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0
pywin32                   227              py37he774522_1
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py37_0
pyyaml                    5.2              py37he774522_0
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37ha925a31_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtconsole                 4.6.0                      py_1
requests                  2.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-toolbelt         0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
retrying                  1.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
rtree                     0.8.3                    py37_0
scipy                     1.3.2            py37h29ff71c_0
seaborn                   0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                44.0.0                   py37_0
shapely                   1.6.4            py37h222a598_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.13.0                   py37_0
sklearn                   0.0                      pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.30.1               he774522_0
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37h8c2d366_0
tensorboard               1.14.0           py37he3c9ec2_0
tensorflow                1.14.0          gpu_py37h5512b17_0
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          gpu_py37h55fc52a_0
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0               h0d30ee6_0
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py37_1
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
time-series               0.2                      pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
tornado                   6.0.3            py37he774522_0
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0
urllib3                   1.25.6                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
xerces-c                  3.2.2                ha925a31_0
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

Comment: Looks like your matplotlib installation is broken.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Any idea how I should fix it?

Comment: First guess is to reinstall matplotlib.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried that but does not seem to work. Do you happen to know which is more stable conda install matplotlib or pip install matplotlib?

Comment: Both are fine. But you would definitely need to uninstall in the same way as you installed. If you have a  conda/pip install, you first need to uninstall completely using conda/pip. Then you can reinstall using pip/conda.

Comment: I tried both, but the weird thing is that when I put conda list I still see matplotlib there, but it does not show up on Anaconda navigator nor does it say its installed but yet its still in the list.

Comment: That might be the problem indeed. Maybe showing the complete line of the matplotlib entry in that list gives someone an idea about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this error after reinstalling `matplotlib` twice and facing other Errors, which are:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
ValueError: 'transform' must be an instance of 'matplotlib.transform.Transform'
```

I was able to solve the above issues by reinstalling `matplotlib` using:

```bash
conda install -f matplotlib
```

But surprisingly I was able to solve this (`ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams' from 'matplotlib'`) just by restarting the `Spyder (Python 3.7)` from File Menu > **Restart** option.

I restarted and then ran the code without any modifications, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```py
from pylab import rcParams
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue above by first uninstalling and installing matplotlib. Then completely creating a new notebook. For some reason the old notebook still gave me the same error but when I create a new notebook in the same environment it worked, go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if this corresponds to a recent change in how `matplotlib` works or if it was always so, but when I encountered the same error, it seemed that the issue was that `rcParams` cannot be directly imported with an import statement. You must first import `matplotlib`, thus causing the module to be loaded into memory, cached, and possibly generate some dynamic objects. *Then* you can access `rcParams`.

Case in point, this fails:

```
import matplotlib.rcParams as rcp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nc/miniconda3/envs/pybnn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3417, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-d4bca3da3c19>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.rcParams as rcp
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/211/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.rcParams'
```

However, this works:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
rcp = mpl.rcParams
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
type(rcp)
Out[5]: matplotlib.RcParams
```

I'm using `matplotlib 3.3.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall anaconda and run again it worked for me