# Module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'rcParams'

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I've used this script to draw plots multiple times, but suddenly bumped into this attribute error.

FYI, I'm in Jupyter Notebook condition, if this matters.

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from matplotlib import gridspec
%matplotlib inline
```

[image]

I checked if the outdated version of Matplotlib was causing the problem, but it seems like it's not the cause.

[image]

Should I delete the package and install it again? Or how can I access `rcParams`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams' from 'matplotlib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936356/importerror-cannot-import-name-rcparams-from-matplotlib)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.